# Django App Served in EBS (Elastic Beanstalk Service) using Traefik and Docker error: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, traefik, cookiecutter-django

I am practicing in deploying a multi-container application using Django Cookiecutter (https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) with TravisCI, Docker, and also using Traefik as router. I already successfully deployed my application to an EBS (Elastic Beanstalk Service) application in AWS with a green health check. The only problem I am currently encountering is if I try to access the hostname or domain that I assigned, I am getting a `502 bad gateway` error. My suspicion is that there is a misconfiguration in either my `traefik.yml` file or my port mappings in `Dockerrunaws.json` file. Please help me find the error.

Here are the configurations:

Please note that "myhostname.com" refers to my actual dns hostname and "myusername" refers to my actual docker hub username.

Also, I used Route 53 to map my hostname with an A name record to my ELB instance.

**traefik.yml**:

```
log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  web:
    # http
    address: ":80"

  flower:
    address: ":5555"

http:
  routers:
    web-router:
      rule: "Host(`myhostname.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django

    flower-router:
      rule: "Host(`myhostname.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - flower
      service: flower

  middlewares:
    csrf:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders
      # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
      headers:
        hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]

  services:
    django:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://django:5000

    flower:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://flower:5555

providers:
  # https://docs.traefik.io/master/providers/file/
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    watch: true
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  production_traefik: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: vincegnzls/test-django
    command: /start

  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: vincegnzls/test-traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
      - "0.0.0.0:5555:5555"

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: vincegnzls/test-celerybeat
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: vincegnzls/test-flower
    command: /start-flower
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "command": [
                "/start"
            ],
            "image": "myusername/test-1",
            "name": "django",
            "memory": 256
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "myusername/test-2",
            "name": "traefik",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 443,
                    "hostPort": 443
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 5555,
                    "hostPort": 5555
                }
            ],
            "memory": 128
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "/start-celerybeat"
            ],
            "image": "myusername/test-3",
            "name": "celerybeat",
            "memory": 128
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "/start-flower"
            ],
            "image": "myusername/test-4",
            "name": "flower",
            "memory": 128
        }
    ]
}
```

**Traefik Dockerfile**

```
FROM traefik:v2.0
RUN mkdir -p /etc/traefik/acme
RUN touch /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
RUN chmod 600 /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
COPY ./compose/production/traefik/traefik.yml /etc/traefik
```

Django Relevant Settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=.myhostname.com
DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False
```

The rest of my Django environment settings are already in the environment properties of my ELB.

Comment: does it work locally?